# Read Enter text in php

Tags: php

I have a problem. I have a text that called from database. In database, the text has an enter text. Here is the picture:

[image]

But in my website, it has no enter. Here is the picture.

[image]

How to read enter in php?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$ambil = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id_blog = '" . $id . "' ");
$deskripsi = $tamp->deskripsi;
?>

<html><body>
    <p><?php echo $deskripsi; ?></p>
</body></html>
```

Thank you before :)

Comment: Please write out the errors and text in your screenshots into the actual description of the question. That way it becomes searchable so future users can easily find your question. Also I would recommend updating your title to make it more clear what you are asking so people are more likely to click on your question.

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php?

Comment: @andrewsi it works man. Many thanks!

Comment: @CharlieFish thank you. i appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<p style="white-space: pre">`.

You could also replace the newlines in the text with `<br>` tags.

The latter can be accomplished like this (hat tip to @andrewsi):

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($deskripsi); ?></p>
```

Comment: Hi @smarx thank you. it works!. so, what is the difference between white-space with nl2br?

Comment: `white-space: pre` tells the browser to put line breaks where it sees newline characters. `nl2br` puts in `<br>` tags where the newlines are. The browser puts line breaks where it sees `<br>` tags. So they accomplish the same thing, just by different means.